# how to install a software with sql database in a domain with different windows clients on windows 2016 server

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2016

I have a domain (Windows 2016) and 4 clients (Windows) attached to it. Now I need a software which hase inbuilt mysql server. How do I install that software so that the software will be accessed from all the clients with common database?

Comment: ask the vendor if its supports a remote database connection

Comment: is it possible that I install the application & sql  on server & then give the sql folder access to clients?

Comment: as i wrote, contact the vendor! And aslong as you either hide the name of thw application neither nor tell us how tits works, the fileshare would be useless